# Authentication of NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am building an API on the MEAN stack. I have been able to successfully create the API for a model called questions. It works for GET, POST, DELETE and PUT requests.

On the website front-end, I want to be able to show questions even when the user is not signed in.

My question is how do I put some kind of authentication in that case? Since users can access the web page with questions even without authentication how do I stop anyone from accessing the API and getting a dump of all the questions?

All tutorials I have been seeing talk about authenticating username and password to allow access to API. How do I resolve my case where user is not signed-in?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it - how do you differentiate amongst users who can see questions and who cannot see , and both being unauthenticated?

Comment: What I mean is how do I stop someone from programatically getting a dump of all the questions. How do I make sure only the web application or say mobile application can get the data from the API?

Comment: try adding client side javascript redirects in response and add a check on server side if user is redirected from desired route, if someone is accessing from non-browser interface javascript would not execute , for API you can try redirects in iframe and use window.postMessage on client side for communication with parent frame

Comment: this mitigates it but, cannot fully solve it as headless browsers like phantomJs can always programatically access your questions, some kind of authentication is the only cure, may be you can add a captcha

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the template on the Server Side using template engine like Jade. in that case, the user from angular side will not hit the API that retrieves the data directly, Instead, he will do a get request to get the html page and your express app will do render the page with the data that you have gathered behind scenes (using controller logic on server side).

This means the angular side will hit something like 'host/pagename', and in express this get request will call another function inside a controller that will retrieve the data (the user will not need to be aware of what is happenning in that function since it is server side) then you can use [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) templates do something like res.render('yourtemplate', {data:'yourdata'}) to render the page for your user without giving him direct access to api